# Two attribute directives with new/isolated scope on single element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'd like to use an AngularJS directive to disable specific parts of forms throughout the application based on whether the user has a specific role (given as attribute value; may be different per element). The directive's code goes like this:

```
/** @ngInject */
function PermissionDirective() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        bindToController: true,
        controller: controller,
        controllerAs: 'permission',
        link: link
    };

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.soPermission = attrs.soPermission;
    }

    return directive;
}

/** @ngInject */
function controller($scope, $attrs, ...) {
    var permission = this;
    permission.granted = false;
    $scope.soPermission = $attrs.soPermission;
    init();

    function init() {
        var requiredPermission = $scope.soPermission;

        permission.granted = // determine if user can use element
    }
}
```

Note that it needs its own scope to work.
The usage in HTML is:

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="... || !permission.granted" so-permission="WRITE">
```

All's fine as long as `so-permission` is the only directive in the element with a new scope. However, some elements also use a [confirm](https://github.com/jameskleeh/angular-confirm/tree/1.2.x) modal which also seems to require a new/isolated scope. This results in a [Multiple directives...](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir) Angular error.

My question is: how do you work around this? How do I rework the `so-permission` directive to get rid of the internal scope and still keep it working (since I can't touch the `confirm` thing as it's a library)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the different permissions you intend to give to the form elements? Maybe stepping back and looking at it from a simpler, HTML perspective is possible?

Instead of creating a directive, could you simply assign the readonly attribute using ng-attr-readonly with a function to determine if it should be present or not. That function could exist in your form's controller.

```
<input type="text" ng-attr-readonly="getPermissions()" />
```

And the function:

```
this.getPermissions = function() {
  if (this.granted === 'READ') return undefined;
  return 'readonly';
}
```

Would this approach work for you situation?

**UPDATE:** Make this function into a Factory and re-use it.

```
angular.module("myApp").factory("PermissionsFactory",PermissionsFactory);
function PermissionsFactory() {

  factory = {
    getPermissions: getPermissions
  }
  return factory;

  function getPermissions(ctrl) {
    if (ctrl.granted === 'READ') return undefined;
    return 'readonly';
  } 

}
```

Then, in your controller (assuming you have injected it):

```
this.getPermissions = PermissionsFactory.getPermissions
```

Finally, in your HTML, be sure to pass the controller into the function, since the function is no longer part of the controller and will need the scope of the controller to check the permissions:

```
<input type="text" ng-attr-readonly="getPermissions(permission)" />
```

Comment: Yes, giving up the directive in favour of a controller function might work for me. I have one doubt though. This function would have to be used throughout the application, which consists of several layers of state in ui-router. I'd like to avoid repeating the function in each and every controller. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Sure! Make it a factory and inject that factory wherever you need it. Then, you can change the function itself in one place, and it will propagate to all uses throughout the application. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Here's when I hit another wall, though. Permissions the user has are taken from a web service. The promise resulting from the call is resolved in ui-router's `resolve`. However, as we detach the function from the controller, we can't use `resolve` anymore. Afaik, there isn't any reasonable way in Angular to force-resolve a promise. There is only the `promise.then() { ... }` idiom, which is useless here because we want the function value right away...

Comment: Depending on the code, you can simply `return true` instead of returning a promise at all in the `resolve` block. If you're getting permissions from a web service, you can simply add a parameter to the PermissionsFactory, instead of the controller, where you pass in the result from the web service. Because I can't see all of what you have written, I don't know if this works for you.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it led me to the most satisfactory solution. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

In angular js, we can have at the most one isolated directive on a single element. I would suggest try to decorate your directive. Check this article for more details 
[Decorating Directives](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/)

Answer (score 0):

you should use $parse service, to communicate with scope:
    /

```
** @ngInject */
        function PermissionDirective() {
        var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };

function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    var getter = $parse(attrs.soPermission);
    var setter = getter.setter;
    setter(scope, val); // set value to scope
    var value = getter(scope); //get value from scope
}

return directive;
}
```

also you could use scope.$watch, to sync values in dynamic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain how it helps solve my problem, which is 1) get rid of the Multiple directives... error, 2) still be able to use the directive for multiple elements with different roles?

Comment: My example can read and edit scope without own scope. It will not throw scope error

Comment: True. But if I understand correctly, when I do it this way, one occurrence of this directive will produce state that will be overwritten by a following occurrence.

Comment: I don't know, how that related to your question. It's fully depends on your code organization. you could use your directive like my-dir="vm.var1" and my-dir="vm.var2" and them will write data to different variables.